Matlab solve differential equations use bvp4c
In Matlab, I use bvp4c to solve equations:
xmesh = linspace(0,pi/2,5);
solinit = bvpinit(xmesh, @guess);

sol = bvp4c(@bvpfcn, @bcfcn, solinit)

function dydx = bvpfcn(x,y) % equation to solve
dydx = zeros(2,1);
dydx = [y(2)
       -y(1)];
end
%--------------------------------
function res = bcfcn(ya,yb) % boundary conditions
res = [ya(1)
       yb(1)-2];
end
%--------------------------------
function g = guess(x) % initial guess for y and y'
g = [sin(x)
     cos(x)];
end

I input 5 points for the initial guess xmesh. However, I got 7 points for the solution:
enter image description here
How can I get the same number of points (i.e., 5 points) for the solution as my initial guess?
